# How to loop a video on flash for air ?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, video, air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash Air video help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964618/flash-air-video-help-needed)

I am making a video based application.In this application a 720p is need to be play loop wise.I have 5 Sec video that should play automatically after 5 Sec i mean loop.I am making this application for Android and IOS.I had tried the looping thing use timer of 5 sec but there is a jerk after each clip.I need a smoothly looping without any jerk after the clip

Thanks in Advance

The following is the i am using.If you know any other code better than this please share else please help me with this code

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.Sprite;

import flash.media.Video;

import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;

import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;   
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var video:Video;
var streamClient:Object;
var connection:NetConnection;
var stream:NetStream; 

streamClient = new Object;
streamClient.onTextData = onTextData;
streamClient.onMetaData = onMetaData;
streamClient.onCuePoint = onCuePoint;

video = new Video();
video.smoothing = true;
addChild(video); 

clickMe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, initiatePlayback);

function initiatePlayback(e:MouseEvent):void
{
connection = new NetConnection ;
    connection.client = streamClient;
connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
connection.connect(null);

myTimer.start();
video.width = 768;
video.height = 1024;
}

function onNetStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void {
        switch (e.info.code){
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
               connectStream();
               break;
            case "NetSream.Buffer.FULL":
               video.width = 768;
               video.height = 1024;
               video.scaleY = video.scaleX;

               break;
        }
    }

  function connectStream():void {
        stream = new NetStream(connection);
        stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
        stream.client = streamClient;

        video.attachNetStream(stream);
        stream.play("movie1.mp4");
    }
    function onTextData(info:Object):void {}
    function onMetaData(info:Object):void {}
    function onCuePoint(info:Object):void {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code related to the timer. You should be able to listen for the video completion inside your onNetStatus event handler

Try this:

```
function onNetStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void {
    switch (e.info.code){
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
           connectStream();
           break;
        case "NetSream.Buffer.FULL":
           video.width = 768;
           video.height = 1024;
           video.scaleY = video.scaleX;

           break;
       /////add this case to make the clip loop

       case "NetStream.Buffer.Empty": //listening for the end of the movie
             stream.play("movie1.mp4"); //play the clip again

       break;

      //try using this to create a gapless playback loop
     case "NetStream.Play.Stop":
           stream.seek(0);
     break;


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me.The code worked well but the main problem remains same after every clips there is gap.Which makes very bad to see the looping video.If you know any way to make video play smoothly without the gap between the clips.Please help...:)

Comment: updated my answer to include another possible solution

Comment: Really thanks for helping me.But the problem remains the same.Note i am making this for android and ios.I test this app on my tablet.You have any other idea to make this better or another method to play video.Please help me if you know.

Comment: You could try embedding the video in your application

Comment: ya i did like that.In my application there is no need to stream video from internet.The video will played from local directory